# Android regular expression to get links of webpage source

Tags: java, android, html, regex, href

I am looking for a RegEx to match links from a webpage source.
If you have any code samples it would be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched it in here? I myself have seen at least a dozen identical request.

Comment: i have searched but i couldn't find for android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match `href` attribute values you can use the following method:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
String link = null;
while (matcher.find())
{
    link = matcher.group(1);
    Log.i("my.regex", "Found link: " + link);
}
```

Comment: @Neeraj, I'm not sure what you mean... mailto is a special anchor attribute. How do you plan to use it here?